Obtain token programatically to go see a page with ASP.NET application
I'm a newbie with authentication and authorization. When I go to a website, it redirects me to a url which requires email and password to login Microsoft Account. If I pass the right credential, it will redirects me to the original page where I want to go.
The login URL looks like this:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{hypothetically-tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?state={
"redirectUrl":"{the-original-url-I-want-to-visit}",
"adminConsentSessionId":null,
"isMFAModeRetry":false
}&client_id={client-id}
&redirect_uri=https://{original-url-domain}/api/auth/azuread/login/code
&response_type=code id_token
&response_mode=form_post
&nonce={nonce}
&scope=openid offline_access
&sso_reload=true

I want to ask if there is a way I can write a flow to provide the credentials to Microsoft if my token expires / not exists, and use the token to see the destination page plus bypassing the login page?
I check the cookie storage and there is a key value pair, if I use that key value pair and place it in the cookie storage, then I won't have to login again. I guess that is the token obtain after the first login.
I also try setting the cookie storage programatically and it works. Of course the cookie key value pair is obtain by myself manually beforehand, so I guess it will expires later on.


newbie with authentication and authorization. When I go to a website,
it redirects me to a url which requires email and password to login
Microsoft Account

The website you visited integrated Azure AD so that you could use Microsoft account to sign in your application. This is authentication, for enforcing sign in to visit the websites. While authorization is deciding which pages are allowed to visit, such as admin could visit the dashboard but normal user couldn't access the dashboard. Here's the samples for using Azure AD, you could refer to the samples and see what Azure AD provides.

write a flow to provide the credentials to Microsoft if my token
expires / not exists, and use the token to see the destination page
plus bypassing the login page

Your requirement might be something already exists but not completely the same. For example, a company uses Azure to manage all their users, then we can use Azure AD so that each user will have a user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com account and the company may wants to its employees to use their onmicrosoft.com account to sign in internal website. This is based on Microsoft Identity platform.
Whenever a user is trying to sign in, the website will redirect to Microsoft sign in page and redirect back to the website after sign in successfully. The remote identity platform will remember the sign-in state(cloud side state), and will give an id token back to the website to let the website application know the user already signed in successfully. Then the application create a cookie which also remember the sign-in state(website side state). After a period of time, the website side state might be expired, and if a user try to visit a page which reqiring auth, the website application will redirect to sign in page again, but this time if the cloud side state hasn't expired, it will bypass the sign in steps and redirect back to the application website again along with the id token so that the application will create a new cookie to upadte the website side state. If the cloud side state also expired, then we have to enter user name and password to sign in again.
The flow you are trying to achivie might not be a good idea as Azure AD SDK already provide feature just like what I described above. About Azure AD authorization flows, you can refer to this series of documentations. These flows are around the access token which helps to achieve who is allowed to access some specific pages.
